# Is it viable to ignore Webkit/Mozilla specific CSS as a developer in 2013?

Tags: html, css, layout, webkit, mozilla

This will probably fall under the 'encouraging debate' category of Stack Overflow but I'd like people to contribute to the answers beyond the point that the question is closed as 'unconstructive'.

As someone migrating from a cross-platform, cross-browser solution like Flash, I am obviously finding the variability of HTML/CSS and it's different browser implementation extremely frustrating. Mulling over an all-encompassing HTML/CSS layout provided by a template site, I'm horrified by the number of browser-specific CSS selectors (like -webkit and -moz) that aim to 'fix' layout issues in legacy/future browsers.

How does a web designer actually go about squaring his demons with the different rendering engines, and is it really necessary for them to essentially learn the nuances of engines like Webkit, Mozilla and Trident? Is it viable to ignore these additions to the styling language in order to leverage simplicity? Every reference book/tutorial I've read seems to glaze over these issues, and the web seems to be made up of many very specific snippets of CSS which address very specific issues.

I'm not looking for condescending answers. I'm aware of the mess of the HTML specification and implementation. But I'm looking for someone to provide me with the best course of action when tackling the problem, and specifically when learning the ropes.

Comment: I really like your question, but i'm afraid the "moderators" will close this down in a few minutes :(

Comment: Dang. I really wish Stack Overflow allowed this sort of question. At least these types of questions are partly informed and interesting - and they do completely revolve around programming and development. These types of question plague programmers/designers on a daily basis, so it seems only fair that they be allowed on a site like this...